# Is it possible to tweet via rest?

Tags: rest, twitter

I would like to tweet via rest but I'm not sure what kind of OAuth I need.
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview
There are plenty of OAuth types. But every time I see that user have to go to the web site and coppy pin(PIN-based OAuth) or go to the web page to sign in or click or something.

So my question is: is it possible to tweet something using only command-line application? (I dont like to use framekorks which are specially prepared for twitter like twitter4j etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update the endpoint to tweet requires authentication.  For this you require a token tied to a specific user.

You have 2 options

1) Generate and store a token beforehand, this is the "Tokens from dev.twitter.com" option in the link you sent.

2) Ask a user to authenticate when you want to tweet for them.  This is "3-legged OAuth" or "PIN-based OAuth".  You can also then store this token for reuse, and switch between tokens in your own code to post as different users.  But it generally relies on a user being logged into Twitter via a browser to click approve at some point before you want to tweet.

My project [oksocial](https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/wiki/Twitter) has support for either approach, after which you can post with

```
oksocial -d "status=my message to the world" https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json
```

or even specify the user token and client secrets on the command line

```
oksocial --token username,consumerKey,consumerSecret,token,secret -d "status=my message to the world" https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json
```

Comment: Yuri, Thanks for commenting! Option 1 seems to be the best. But what kind of token I have to do with this 4 values from dev.twitter.com?

Comment: You still need to sign each request individually. The signature is a combination of user token/secret, client secret, time and request details. But at that point you just don't need a real user involved. there is plenty of example code for signing and even command line clients including the project I linked to.

Comment: Ok, so all I need is signature ( https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures ) [I already have this] and after this I have to tweet as described in ( https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests )?

Comment: Yep, as I showed above, if you have this information username,consumerKey,consumerSecret,token,secret and an implementation to generate a signature for a request you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna post tweet from a command line then maybe https://github.com/sferik/t can help you. Regards